# FTP Sync Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, ftp, permissions, winscp

I have a Powershell script that is scheduled to run every 15 minutes to check an external FTP folder for new files.  If there are new files, it will grab these files and move them to our FTP folder.

I also have a log step that will email when files have been transferred and also when there is an error.  There is no message when there is a successful check but no files are found.

I keep receiving this error in the log and I cannot figure out why:

Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond - WinSCP has not responded in time.  This could indicate lack of write permissions to the log folder or problems starting WinSCP itself.

However, the script writes fine to the log when files are transferred, but seems to get this error all throughout the day when it is running sweeps.

Has anyone every seen this?

Comment: You should give your code if youwants some help.

Comment: *"script writes fine to the log"*: What log do you refer to? Do you get the error always, even when the *"script"* (do you refer to the PowerShell script?) transfers files?